# Numpy loadtxt skiprow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to use numpy.loadtxt to load an array from a `.csv` file with a header.

```
data = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=1,delimiter=',')
```

I get an error (could not convert string to float). I think it isn't actually skipping the header row, which contains strings. I experimented with changing the file extension to a `.txt` and that fixed it for some reason...

Comment: We would need to see the file to figure out what is going on.  Check the file carefully--there may be other lines besides the first that contain nonnumeric text.  The filename extension should not matter.

Comment: I believe there was some other collateral change. Does it stop working if you convert it back to a `.csv`?

Comment: I changed the file back to a *.csv and it had no issue.  I'm not entirely sure why.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to have been some formatting issues with that specific *.csv file.  Hopefully this issue doesn't come back.